# Popular DataGridView Editável C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

Fiz um Form de edição de Tipos de Produtos onde ele tem um UserControl com a lista de Tipos de Campos Adicionais.

No método de adicionar está tudo certo.

No UserControl tem um DataGridView editável onde criei um DataGridViewTextBoxColumn e um DataGridViewComboBoxColumn visíveis.

Eu populo o ComboBox com os tipos de formatos de campos disponíveis no banco, é só o que o usuário pode selecionar (String, Int32 etc).

Meu **problema** é **popular o DataGridView** com os **dados do Model** para edição.

Eu utilizo um Repository para receber todos os dados do banco retornando um Model.

Todas as pesquisas que fiz apontam para a utilização de **instrução SQL diretamente no Formulário**. O que não posso fazer para não sair do padrão escolhido. (é um misto de MVVM com MVC) feito com o  pouco conhecimento que ainda tenho. “tá uma verdadeira bagunça mas não vou entrar nesse mérito”.

**TipoProdutoListUC.cs:**

```
    //chamado do formulário para edição do Tipo de Produto
    //mesmo formulário utilizado para Edit e Add
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TipoProdutoModel = _tipoProdutoServices.GetById(int.Parse(this.dgvTiposProdutos.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
            TipoProdutoAddForm tipoProdutoForm = new TipoProdutoAddForm(this.CatalogoForm, this);
            tipoProdutoForm.Text = "Editando Tipo de Produto";
            tipoProdutoForm.TipoProdutoModel = this.TipoProdutoModel;
            tipoProdutoForm.CatalogoModel = this.CatalogoModel;
            tipoProdutoForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            tipoProdutoForm.ShowDialog();
            this.TiposProdutosListUC_Load(sender, e);
        }
```

**TipoProdutoAddForm.cs:**

[image: TipoProdutoAddForm]

```
private void LoadUserControlCamposAdicionais()
        {
            camposAdicionais = new CamposTiposProdutosListUC(this);
            camposAdicionais.TipoProdutoModel = this.TipoProdutoModel;
            panelCampos.Controls.Clear();
            panelCampos.Controls.Add(camposAdicionais);
            camposAdicionais.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
```

**Chamando o método Add or Update**

```
//a função ADICIONAR é feita todo no TipoProdutoAddForm.
//Quero fazer a função Update em seguida. Também toda nele.
       private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled))
            {
                if (this.TipoProdutoModel.TipoProdutoId != 0)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        TipoProdutoUpdate();
                        CampotipoUpdate();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível atualizar o Tipo de Produto", "Atualizando Tipo de Produto");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.TipoProdutoModel = TipoProdutoAdd();
                        this.ListaCamposAdicionais = CampoTipoAdd();
                        MessageBox.Show($"Tipo de Produto Adicionado com sucesso", "Adicionando Tipo de Produto");

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível adicionar o Tipo de Produto");
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

**Método TipoProdutoAdd()**

```
        private TipoProdutoModel TipoProdutoAdd()
        {
            TipoProdutoModel returnedModel = new TipoProdutoModel();

            this.TipoProdutoModel = new TipoProdutoModel()
            {
                CatalogoId = this.CatalogoModel.CatalogoId,
                Descricao = this.textTipoProduto.Text
            };

            bool operationSucceeded = false;
            string dataAccesStatusJsonStr = string.Empty;
            string formattedJsonStr = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                returnedModel = _tipoProdutoServices.Add(this.TipoProdutoModel);

            }
            catch (DataAccessException e)
            {
                operationSucceeded = e.DataAccessStatusInfo.OperationSucceeded;
                dataAccesStatusJsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e.DataAccessStatusInfo);
                formattedJsonStr = JToken.Parse(dataAccesStatusJsonStr).ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(formattedJsonStr, "Não foi possível adicionar o Tipo de Produto", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }



            if (operationSucceeded)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Registro Salvo com sucesso", "Salvando Tipo  do Distribuidor", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }

            return returnedModel;
        }
```

**Método CampoTipoAdd()**

```
        private List<CampoTipoProdutoModel> CampoTipoAdd() //que que eu vou fazer com a lista retornada???
        {
            List<CampoTipoProdutoModel> modelList = new List<CampoTipoProdutoModel>();
            DataGridViewRowCollection rowsCamposAdicionais;
            rowsCamposAdicionais = this.camposAdicionais.dgvCampos.Rows; //peguei as linhas do DATAGRID
                                                                         //modelList = camposAdicionais.dgvCampos.Columns.

            bool operationSucceeded = false;
            string dataAccesStatusJsonStr = string.Empty;
            string formattedJsonStr = string.Empty;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rowsCamposAdicionais)
            {
                if (row.Cells["ColumnNome"].Value != null)
                {
                    CampoTipoProdutoModel model = new CampoTipoProdutoModel();
                    model.Nome = row.Cells["ColumnNome"].Value.ToString();
                    model.FormatoId = int.Parse(row.Cells["ColumnFormato"].Value.ToString());
                    model.TipoProdutoId = this.TipoProdutoModel.TipoProdutoId;
                    modelList.Add(model);
                }
            }

            if (modelList.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (CampoTipoProdutoModel model in modelList)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _campoTipoProdutoServices.Add(model);

                    }
                    catch (DataAccessException e)
                    {
                        operationSucceeded = e.DataAccessStatusInfo.OperationSucceeded;
                        dataAccesStatusJsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e.DataAccessStatusInfo);
                        formattedJsonStr = JToken.Parse(dataAccesStatusJsonStr).ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(formattedJsonStr, "Não foi possível adicionar o Tipo de Produto", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }

                }
            }
            return modelList;

        }
```

Agora vem a Cereja do Bolo:
O UserControl que tem a lista de Tipos de Produtos.

**CamposTipsProdutosListUC.cs:**

[image: DataGridView]

[image: DataGridViewComboBoxColumn]

```
//Todos esse IF’s são para identificar se está adicionando ou atualizando.
//caso null está adicionando.
//esse !=0 é para não dá erro pois ele pega a Lista de Campos pelo ID do Tipo de Produto. 
        private void CamposTiposProdutosListUC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                if (this.TipoProdutoModel != null)
                {
                    if (this.TipoProdutoModel.TipoProdutoId != 0)
                    {
                        ListaCampos = (List<CampoTipoProdutoModel>)_camposServices.GetAllByTipoProdutoId(TipoProdutoModel.TipoProdutoId);
                    }
                }
                ConfiguraDGV();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

**Método ConfiguraDGV()**

```
//Configurando e populando a DataGrid.
//meu problema está aqui.
        private void ConfiguraDGV()
        {

            PopulaComboBoxFormatos();

            if (ListaCampos != null)
            {
                if (ListaCampos.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.ListaCampos = PopulaDgv();

                    dgvCampos.VirtualMode = true;
                    dgvCampos.AutoSize = true;
                    dgvCampos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                    dgvCampos.DataSource = this.ListaCampos; //vai antes ou depois dos foreaches?

                    //pra cada linha adiciona um model da lista
                    foreach (CampoTipoProdutoModel modelCampo in this.ListaCampos)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvCampos.Rows)
                        {
//Não sei mais o que fazer para os dados do Model ir para o DataGridView
                            row.Cells["ColumnCampoTipoId"].Value = modelCampo.CampoTipoId.ToString();
                            row.Cells["ColumnNome"].Value = modelCampo.Nome.ToString();
                            row.Cells["ColumnFormato"].Value = modelCampo.FormatoId;
                            row.Cells["ColumnTipoProdutoId"].Value = modelCampo.TipoProdutoId;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

E por último e não menos importante:
**O método PopulaComboBoxFormatos()**

```
        public void PopulaComboBoxFormatos()
        {
            List<FormatoCampoModel> modelsFormatos = new List<FormatoCampoModel>();
            try
            {

                modelsFormatos = (List<FormatoCampoModel>)_formatoServices.GetAll();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            ColumnFormato.ValueMember = "FormatoId";
            ColumnFormato.DisplayMember = "Nome";
            ColumnFormato.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var model in modelsFormatos)
            {
                ColumnFormato.Items.Add(model);
            }

        }
```

Já tentei de todo o jeito fazer as células da linha carregar os dados do Model mas não sei o que fazer mais.
Se eu mudo para DataTable eu fico perdido para preencher o ComboBox.
Quero poder obter preencher os dados da Grid com os models.
Já pesquisei de todo o jeito. Tive que restaurar os arquivos no GIT várias vezes pq quando eu tento corrigir utilizando DataTable não consigo mais Ler os itens do ComboBox.
Se alguém puder me dar uma luz eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: *"Meu problema é popular o DataGridView com os dados do Model "* o DataGridView aceita como data souce uma `List` por exemplo, só criar um `List<Model>` e usar na propriedade `DataSource` e chamar o métod `Bind()` que vai funcionar

Comment: Então não preciso fazer esse foreach. 
Posso apenas usar a ListCampos, que já é uma List<model> e usar no DataSource.
Vou ver alguns detalhes sobre o Bind(). Nunca usei.
Vou tentar... dpois dou um feedback. vlw

Comment: Tem outra questão: o Model do DataGrid retornar um inteiro do Formato.
O Formato em texto para o usuário vem do ComboBox ColumnFormato. Não vai dar ruim?

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu já estava usando o DataSource=this.ListaCampos

Esse ListaCampos é um List<Model>.

Não estava querendo que ele gerasse as colunas automaticamente pois eu tenho que tratar a segunda coluna quem no Model tem um ID. E eu tenho que passar os dados de Outro Model que está no ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi um problema e me deparei com outro.

@RicardoPontual acho que você não entendeu o problema. Mas obrigado mesmo assim pela ajuda.

Primeiro para trazer o Model para o DataGrid usei um exemplo do [Docs da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=net-5.0) passando um array de string com os valores do Model encontrado.

**Método ConfiguraDGV()**

Esse fica somente com **um** foreach e usei um **for** para cada item da `List<ListaCampos>`.

Esses `row.Cells` não ajudam em nada pois o valor vem sempre nulo.

**Removi** o `DataSource`, pois vou gerar manualmente por meio do `Array`, além de remover o VirtualMode para poder popular manualmente as linhas.

Então Ficou Assim:

```
private void ConfiguraDGV()
{
   PopulaComboBoxFormatos();
   if (ListaCampos != null)
   {
      if (ListaCampos.Count > 0)
      {
        this.ListaCampos = PopulaDgv();
        //dgvCampos.VirtualMode = true;
        dgvCampos.AutoSize = true;
        dgvCampos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        //dgvCampos.DataSource = this.ListaCampos;
        
        
        //pra cada linha adiciona um model da lista
        foreach (CampoTipoProdutoModel modelCampo in this.ListaCampos)
        {
            //para cada registro da LIsta de Campos adiciona um array à linha do DGV.
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaCampos.Count; i++)
            {
                string[] stringRow =
                {
                    modelCampo.CampoTipoId.ToString(),
                    modelCampo.Nome.ToString(),
                    //O Nome do Formato vem de outro Model, mas busquei do Repository diretamente.
                    //TODO: Melhorar isso
                    _formatoServices.GetById(modelCampo.FormatoId).Nome.ToString()
                };
                dgvCampos.Rows.Add(stringRow);
            }
            
        }
      }
   }
}
```

**Segundo Problema**
O ComboBox estava configurado errado.
Alterei o VAlueMember de FormatoId para Nome
problema resolvido.

```
ColumnFormato.DataPropertyName = "FormatoId";
ColumnFormato.ValueMember = "Nome";
ColumnFormato.DisplayMember = "Nome";
ColumnFormato.Items.Clear();
foreach (var model in modelsFormatos)
{
 ColumnFormato.Items.Add(model);
}
```

Fica aí pra quem tiver o mesmo problema que eu tive. Se encontrar uma solução melhor, me informem.

Mais uma vez obrigado @RicardoPontual pela ajuda. Serviu muito para eu buscar mais etendimento.